# Como simplificar o código usando um laço?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, loop, ado.net

Como posso simplificar o código abaixo utilizando um laço, estou na dúvida em função do nome dos *labels* que estão sequenciais, como coloco algo variável em NomeCampo1, `NomeCampo2`, ..., `NomeCampoX`.

```
lblNomeCampo1.Text = dt.Rows[1][0].ToString()+":";
lblCampo1.Text = dt.Rows[1][1].ToString();
lblNomeCampo2.Text = dt.Rows[2][0].ToString() + ":";
lblCampo2.Text = dt.Rows[2][1].ToString();
lblNomeCampo3.Text = dt.Rows[3][0].ToString() + ":";
lblCampo3.Text = dt.Rows[3][1].ToString();
lblNomeCampo4.Text = dt.Rows[4][0].ToString() + ":";
lblCampo4.Text = dt.Rows[4][1].ToString();
lblNomeCampo5.Text = dt.Rows[5][0].ToString() + ":";
lblCampo5.Text = dt.Rows[5][1].ToString();
lblNomeCampo6.Text = dt.Rows[6][0].ToString() + ":";
lblCampo6.Text = dt.Rows[6][1].ToString();
lblNomeCampo7.Text = dt.Rows[7][0].ToString() + ":";
lblCampo7.Text = dt.Rows[7][1].ToString();
lblNomeCampo8.Text = dt.Rows[8][0].ToString() + ":";
lblCampo8.Text = dt.Rows[8][1].ToString();
lblNomeCampo9.Text = dt.Rows[9][0].ToString() + ":";
lblCampo9.Text = dt.Rows[9][1].ToString();
lblNomeCampo10.Text = dt.Rows[10][0].ToString() + ":";
lblCampo10.Text = dt.Rows[10][1].ToString();
```

Comment: Qual linguagem? Explique melhor esse código ai.

Comment: Amigo, cada linguagem tem suas particularidades. Favor mencionar a linguagem. Isso é básico em todas as perguntas. Quantos mais detalhes, melhor.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 3):

Essencialmente não dá nesta forma. Daria com reflexão, mas não acho que compense.

Dá para reestruturar o formulário que lida com isto fazendo com que os campos sejam elementos de *array* também, aí tudo que os envolva podem ser usados com um laço. Aí poderia fazer assim:

```
lblNomeCampo[i].Text = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString() + ":";
lblCampo[i].Text = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/WinForms/LoopItens.cs).

Todas as vezes que tem várias variáveis com nomes que tenham uma sequencia de números como sufixo pode substituir por um *array* (ou estrutura semelhante) de forma simples e direta, ou seja, basta mudar o número fixo pelo índice do *array*.

Obviamente que tem que criar o *array* e criar os objetos de tela em cima dos elementos do *array*.

Cada elemento do *array* é uma variável como outra qualquer, nada muda nele exceto o fato que ela é acessada pelo conjunto do nome mais o índice. Então as trate desta forma.

Esta solução independe da linguagem, ainda que seria melhor saber qual é (pelo que entendi é C#).

Answer (score -1):

Não é a melhor maneira mas poderia fazer algo assim, eu não entendo muito de C#, mas o caminho é mais ou menos este:

```
for (var i=1; i <= 10; i++) {
   Eval("lblNomeCampo"+i+".Text = dt.Rows["+i+"][0].ToString() + \":\";");
   Eval("lblCampo"+i+".Text = dt.Rows["+i+"][1].ToString() + \":\";");
}
```

Eu sugiro algo mais bem elaborado, tipo:

```
   foreach (int i in dt.Rows) {
       lblNomeCampo[i].Text = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString() + ":";
       lblCampo[i].Text = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString() + ":";
   }
```

Deixa os campos no form assim:

```
name="lblNomeCampo[]"

name="lblCampo[]"
```

Comment: Que Eval é este?

Comment: Eu estou pensando que deve haver alguma forma de converter o objeto usando eval, assim como é feito em javascript.

Comment: Mas não tem, pelo menos não de forma simples assim. E mesmo assim, não tem porque fazer desta forma quando o *array* funciona. Mesmo em JS ninguém deveria fazer isto.

Comment: Eu concordo... por isso disse que não é a melhor maneira.

Comment: talvez usando: myObject.Field = Convert.ChangeType(value, fieldType);

Comment: Não. é bem mais complicado, e vai contra a filosofia da linguagem, embora seja algo ruim em qualquer linguagem usar um recurso pior quando tem um melhor que faz a mesma coisa.

Comment: ou tipo isso: Type myTypeA = typeof(MyFieldClassA); FieldInfo myFieldInfo = myTypeA.GetField("Field");

Comment: Também não, não adianta, não está nem perto. Não vale a pena perder tempo com algo ruim assim.

Comment: Bom, eu publiquei uma segunda opção, que acredito ser a melhor... e mais elaborada. Vai da pessoa, o que ele prefere usar (não usaria, em meus códigos)... quanto a linguagem, pouco importa pra mim, não sou eu que estou escrevendo o código. Só estou mostrando opções...

Comment: Dá pra ver que o objeto em si que ele está fazendo já está dentro da proposta de XGH, pra começar...